# Getting Actual String from Python XML parsing

Tags: python, xml

I have a string that when parsed with `tostring` gives me a bunch of xml. Is there a way to get that fixed?

For example, when i run `ET.tostring(elementObject,,encoding='us-ascii', method='xml')`, i get `<string>11&gt;2</string>`. I am expecting: "11>2". Is there a way to get what I am expecting or do I need to do some regex on that return value?

I am using `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ET.tostring()` is meant to produce a XML string for a given element, not the *contained string value*. Use the [`Element.text` attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text) instead:

```
elementObject.text
```

Demo:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.fromstring('''\
... <root><string>11&gt;2</string></root>''')
>>> root.find('string')
<Element 'string' at 0x103332990>
>>> root.find('string').text
'11>2'
```